# How to optimize super large objects for large scene rendering

Tags: optimization

we are trying to render a large solar farm.
For this we used procedural textures, pipes with textures you name it.
Each solar panel strip is about 100m / 100 yards long.
Our goal is to have a complete "farm" of these panels.

By the time we try and put them all together in the final scene it's just too big with gigas and gigas
of file size, something in the order of about 6GB for simple simple rows of solar panels with piping. Crazy!
It seems that somehow blender multiplies everything in order to achieve these in my opinion crazy files sizes, instead of somehow linking the procedural textures and not increasing the file size.

In the included link, I have uploaded photos of what is we are trying to do and
a blender file (2.92) with the object we have created from which we multiply into these large 100m strips.

I've attached a photo of what it is we would like to render (in the final this will be multiplied by a multiple of 20 or 30).
I've also attached a link with the objects in it, maybe somebody would be so kind to take a look and see how and where we could optimize this.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TB8ifa89ATvDatlNoAeRez-BMDKZ5bms?usp=sharing

Are there any tools that could optimize such a process? Any baking tools that could help slim down these objects automatically?

Much appreciate your help!
Thanks a million :-)
Kind regards!

Comment: You've got about 50k faces on a single nut and bolt my guy!

Comment: Wow! Thanks. We'll look into that one right away.